# Select first 10 rows and display into a slideshow

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a website and I want to display my data into a slideshow from database. The slideshow is made using bootstrap.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
require 'includes/dbh-inc.php';

function make_query($conn)
{
    $query = " SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    return $result;
}

function make_slide_indicators($conn)
{
    $output = '';
    $count = 0;
    $result = make_query($conn);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($count == 0)
        {
            $output .= '<li data-target="#dynamic_slide_show" data-slide-to="'.$count.'" class="active"></li>
            ';
        } else {
            $output .= '<li data-target="#dynamic_slide_show" data-slide-to="'.$count.'"></li>';
        }
        $count = $count + 1 ;
    }
    return $output;
}

function make_slides($conn)
{
    $output = '';
    $count = 0;
    $result = make_query($conn);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if($count == 0)
        {
            $output .= '<div class="item active">';
        } else {
            $output .= '<div class="item">';
        }
        $output .= '<img src="images/notes/'.$row["image"]
                .'" alt="'.$row["denomination"].'" style=" width: 100%;height: 300px;" /> 
                <div class="carousel-caption"> 
                <h3>' .$row['price'].'</h3>
                </div>';
        $count = $count +1;
    }
    return $output;
}
?>

<main> 
    <div class="container">
        <h2 align="center">Pedigree Notes</h2>
        <br />
        <div id="dynamic_slide_show" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <?php echo make_slide_indicators($conn); ?>
            </ol>

            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <?php echo make_slides($conn); ?>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>

        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

It is working somehow, but it displays both pictures from database in first slide, half slide first pictures the other half the second picture.
Can you please tell me what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: You can start with LIMIT 10 in SELECT.

Comment: I did, same result i only have 10 rows in database

Comment: I don't see it.

Comment: me neither... that's why im asking for help

Comment: Funny, you said you did, but I didn't see where you used LIMIT.

Comment: "You can start with LIMIT 10 in SELECT" Do that @FunkFortyNiner says "I did, same result i only have 10 rows in database" What is going to happen if you have more records in your table without using `LIMIT 10` ?

Comment: then i will set the limit, either i set the limit or not it display the same result

Comment: Yes because have 10 records in the table... Because off your title "Select first 10 rows.." we assume you want to use `LIMIT 10`...

Comment: yes i know, sorry about that, i dont know why its displaying 2 images on a slide instead of 1

Comment: Did you check the HTML source and confirmed all 10 images and slice indicators where generated? And the generated HTML is valid HTML?

Comment: yes i did, i took the template from bootstrap, i only add the php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function make_slides, change the class item to carousel-item

```
if($count == 0)
{
   $output .= '<div class="carousel-item active">';
} else {
        $output .= '<div class="carousel-item">';
}
```

Comment: may i ask you another question? how can i make it a permanent query? because when the 10 slides is done , the slideshow dissapears and the first slide is displayed as is it, but the rest 9 are like flash

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by permanent query. In the code above, it appears that you make one query and pull back the data at once into the bootstrap carousel. The carousel should continue cycling as long as you have data-ride="carousel" (which it appears that you have). If the slideshow is not cycling (or stops), I'm wondering if there is a javascript error. Do you notice any errors in the console section of developer tools?

Comment: I think your problem is that you didn't close a <div> In the PHP function "make_slides", for the value of the variable $output, add another </div> after the current </div>. That should fix it. :)